# How can I speed up this json string cleaning function?

Tags: r, optimization, jsonlite

I am storing alternative names for country administrative districts in a json string, and I have a function to clean up NA and duplicate values; however, it is a very slow function, particularly when I have tens of thousands of rows in some of the data. I've been using tidy syntax because I am the most familiar with it. It works, but does anyone have ideas on how I can optimize this function?

Here is some example data and the function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(rio)
library(jsonlite)
library(tictoc)


data <- import(
  'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zd_gUj4ejZoTph5i7l_XTRg3pIS2_6tM2mde0SFykzM/edit?usp=sharing',
  setclass = 'tibble'
)

cleanAlternateNames <- function(altNames) {
  tic()
  altNames %<>% lapply(function(x) {
    if (!x %>% is.na()) {
      x %>% fromJSON() %>% plyr::ldply(rbind) %>%
        pivot_longer(-one_of('.id')) %>%
        filter(!is.na(value),!value == 'NA') %>%
        distinct(value, .keep_all = T) %>%
        select(-name) %>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = '.id', values_from = 'value') %>%
        toJSON()
    }
  })
  toc()
  return(altNames)
}

data %<>%
  mutate(AlternateNames = AlternateNames %>% str_replace_all('""','"') %>% 
           cleanAlternateNames)
```

I modified the sample data to provide a better range of what I am trying to convert.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, none of your example data has two rows, and thus `rbind` and `pivot_longer` seem unnecessary. Perhaps you could 1) provide data that requires this functionality and 2) clarify the important aspects of your expected output.

Comment: When fromjson is called it creates a data frame with multiple rows. This data frame is then filtered for NA and duplicate values and then converted back to a json string. It is basically storing a dataframe as a json string, although the strings are of different lengths.

Comment: This code `data$AlternateNames %>% str_replace_all('""','"') %>% map(fromJSON)` results in a list of length `99`, each element of which is a list, which contains a single character vector.

Comment: Thank you, that does quickly convert it to a list. I've been struggling to find a way to filter the NA values and duplicates out of the lists though. I updated the raw data to include a better sample of the data I'm dealing with.

Comment: You've pretty substantially changed the question with your edit. Good luck!

Comment: It's still the same question, just sample data that's better representative of what I'm dealing with. I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the helpful example uses of map from [Ian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13095326/ian-campbell) and another user I was able to go back in my code to where I originally combined json lists and remove duplicates and duplicates using the map function. This code is significantly faster and eliminates the need to use the function I was using to try to clean the code afterwards. I'm posting this here in case anyone has similar problem.s

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(rio)
library(jsonlite)

# filters out duplicates from first string
.lfilter <- function(x1,x2){
  nm <- names(x1)
  x1 %<>%  unlist
  x1 <- x1[!x1 %in% unlist(x2)] 
  if(length(x1) > 0){
    x1 %<>%
      unname() %>% 
      list() %>% set_names(nm)
  }
  return(x1)
}

# combines two columns that are in json format while removing duplicates
.combineJSONlists <- function(x){
  x %<>% str_split("\\|")
  x1 <- x[[1]][1] %>% fromJSON()
  x2 <- x[[1]][-1] %>% fromJSON() 
  x1 <- map(x1, .lfilter, x2 = x2)
  com <- x1  %>% c(x2) %>% toJSON()
  return(com)
}

# load data
data <- import(
  'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zd_gUj4ejZoTph5i7l_XTRg3pIS2_6tM2mde0SFykzM/edit?usp=sharing',
  setclass = 'tibble'
)

# combine new and old AlternateNames
data %<>%
  mutate(
    ISO = ISO %>% str_replace_all('""','"'),
    AlternateNames = AlternateNames %>% str_replace_all('""','"') %>% 
      paste0("|",ISO),
    AlternateNames = AlternateNames %>%
      map_chr(.combineJSONlists)) %>% 
  select(-ISO)
```